# Getting a fair result from an unfair non-independent coin

Tags: probability, random-variables

It's well known that if you have a biased coin, where the heads has probability `p` and tails `q=1-p`, you can get an unbiased toss by tossing the coin twice and taking the first toss if they differ and retossing if they are the same. This technique is called the von  Neumann extractor.

This, of course, assumes that the coin tosses are independent. I'm interested in the case where they are not independent.

In particular, let $p_H$ be the probability of throwing a head after getting a head, and $q_H$ be that of getting a tail after throwing a head. (So that $p_H + q_H = 1$) Define $p_T$ and $q_T$ similarly.

Applying the von Neumann extractor to this generates a non-independant sequence. Intuitively I expect that if each throw is positively correlated with the previous one then the extracted sequence will be negatively correlated and vice-versa.

So my questions are

- Is my intuition about the correlation of the extracted sequence correct, and can the correlation of the extracted sequence be made more explicit?
- Is there a similar simple process able to convert such a correlated sequence into a fair, unbiased and uncorrelated one.

Comment: What are you assuming about the very first toss?

Comment: Regardless of the first toss:  Imagine your coin has two states, a "Heads" state (if the prior toss was H) and a "Tails" state. In each of those states the coin behaves like a normal weighted coin so you can use the standard approach.

Comment: @lulu: Right, and you should put that as an answer. =) I believe it should also be easy to show that it is optimal via computing the total entropy of the resulting extracted sequences.

Comment: @lulu: Sorry I was referring to the version which didn't discard but stored them in levels, which can be applied to each of your states separately.

Comment: @user21820 Not entirely sure I have a handle on your variant, certainly mine is fairly wasteful.  If your method is more efficient (which I can easily believe) it probably makes more sense to write that one up.

Comment: @user21820  Oh, are you just saying "toss the coin lots of times and keep track of the two sequences 'tosses of the Heads coin' and 'tosses of the Tails coin' " and then simply refer to these two sequences as needed?

Comment: @lulu: No I was referring to the solution for independent bits that does not discard any bit. See http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/coinflipext.pdf. Given that the advanced multi-level algorithm described there is optimal, it should be easy to prove that applying it to each of the two states in this problem yields an optimal algorithm.

Comment: @user21820  Got it.  Nice reference!  I agree that it should be easy to adapt to the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the core idea from the comments; here is a simple way to extract a fair coin toss from the given situation:

Note that at any given moment (except possibly prior to the first toss) the coin is in one of two states, "Heads" or "Tails" according to whatever the prior toss was.  In either state the coin behaves like an ordinary weighted coin, so the standard method for extracting a fair toss applies. To be specific, toss the coin once to get it in one state or the other.  For the sake of definiteness, let's say it comes up H so the coin starts as "Heads".  Now toss it a lot of times.  Say we get the sequence: $$\{H,H,T,H,T,T,T,T,H,T,T,H,H,T,H,H,H\}$$  Split that in two, so we are recording the tosses of the Heads coin and the tosses of the Tails coin.  In this case we'd get (trusting that no errors were made): $$\mathscr H =\{H,H,T,T,T,H,T,H,H\}$$
$$\mathscr T=\{H,T,T,T,H,T,H,H\}$$
Now we apply the standard extractor to either of the coins.  If you had chosen the Tails coin, the first two tosses are $H,T$ so von Neumann would tell us we chose $H$.  Had you chosen the Heads coin the first two tosses are $H,H$ which we must discard.  The next pair is $T,T$ which we also discard.  The third pair is $T,H$ so we have selected $T$.

As @user21820 rightly observes in the comments, the efficiency of this method can be improved significantly (the outlined method generally requires you to discard a lot of tosses).  The [reference given](http://eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/coinflipext.pdf) is clear and can be applied to the two sequences I have described.

Note I:  a variant question may be of some interest. Suppose the coin is not modeled by any sensible finite state system.  That is, suppose the next toss depends non-trivially on the entire history (suppose, of course, that the nature of this dependence is fully specified).  Now the "disentangling" method sketched above does not appear to apply. Can we still extract a fair toss?   (to be clear, I have not spent any time at all on this. )

Note II (sketch): as to the correlation.  The OP's intuition is correct but it doesn't appear to be trivial to see that.  To be precise, let $p_H$ denote the probability that the Heads coin comes up H and let $\pi_T$ denote the probability that the Tails coin comes up T (slightly different notation that appeared in the question).  We assume that $p_H,\pi_T > .5$ and we need to compute $\phi$, the probability that von Neumann returns H starting from the Heads coin, and $\psi$, the probability that von Neumann returns H starting from the Tails coin. This is simple, if messy, to do via recursions (just looking at the four possible outcomes of the first two tosses. We get that $$(1-p_H^2)\phi=p_H(1-p_H)+(1-p_H)\pi_T\psi$$ $$(1-\pi_T^2)\psi=(1-\pi_T)(1-p_H)+(1-\pi_T)p_H\phi$$  After some tedious algebra we get that $$\phi=\frac {p_H+\pi_T}{1+p_H+\pi_T}$$ And it is easy to see that this is greater than $\frac 12$.  By symmetry we also get $\psi<\frac 12$.  Thats all we need!  It means that, starting from Heads we are more likely to get H than T (which means we'll switch to the Tails coin) and from the Tails coin we are more likely to get T than H (which means we'll switch to the Heads coin).  There may, of course, be a more intuitive argument for this.

Comment: This is beautifully simple, and answers the second half of the question. I don't suppose you have any insight into the first half - quantifying the correlation if you blindly apply von Neumann?

Comment: Sorry, didn't try to analyze that and haven't got time now.  I'll take a look in the morning.  To clarify:  in this case by positive correlation you mean that the coin is more likely to equal the last toss whatever it was?

Comment: That's fine - not meant as a criticism in any way - more an explanation for why I might delay accepting ;) And yep - that's exactly what I meant by positive correlation.

Comment: At a quick glance, I share your intuition with a small reservation.  Starting with the Heads coin and assuming the first pair is indecisive, it is not certain that you are more likely to stay in the Heads state.  That might complicate matters, not sure.  Well, I'll take a better look later.

Comment: Your intuition is correct but (I think) non-trivial.  I'll edit my post and sketch the proof.